# Outputting a whole array at once

Tags: c++

I have a large 1D array of chars and I'm looking for a way to output the whole array without using the usual for-loop and doing this in a single output rather then thousands of outputs, the reason being performance and execution time reduction.

Is there anyway to be able to achieve this?

Comment: Are there any nulls within the array? If not, can you put a null in the last one and then use something like printf or cout?

Comment: Is it a pure char [], or is it some STL container? If it is an STL container, it should be vector. If it's pure char[], where is the problem?

Comment: It is a pure char array, no nulls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// If it's null-terminated
#include <stdio.h>
printf( "%s\n", myarray );
```

Comment: with this option, my program doesn't terminate, its stuck in a constant loop of outputting the array, any advice?

Comment: After playing around with this option, this turned out to be the fastest. Thanks  :)

Comment: Sorry I missed your previous comment - really glad to hear it's working.  What was the problem?

Answer (score 9):

An alternative is to use [`ostream::write`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/write/) which accepts a char array and the array size. The array is copied directly to the streambuffer, so it skips the formatting steps.

**Edit**

```
//since, std::cout is an ostream ...
std::cout.write( array, 8 );
```

Comment: thanks for the advice, can you help me in understanding this method? i'm struggling to implement this

Comment: @Jono_2007, I added an example.

Comment: sorry took so long to reply, it worked, thank you for explaining it to me, but it turned out to be very slow with repeating it in my program so many times. I believe this will be useful for future applications though, thanks  :)

Answer (score 5):

As a general case, use `std::copy` as:

```
T a[N]; //N is some constant!
//...
std::copy(a, a + N, std::ostream_iterator<T>(std::cout, " "));
```

Replace `T` with `char`, `int`, `std::string` or any type, it should work, as long as `operator<<` is overloaded for `T`, either as member function of `std::ostream` or free function which takes `std::ostream&` as first argument, and `const T&` as second argument.

Comment: I have a suspicion that space-delimiting is less-than-useful with character elements. Also, I suppose that the trailing space could be an annoyance

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind taking a copy,

```
std::cout << std::string(a, a+N) << std::endl;
```

wrapping it into a generic function:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
std::ostream& dump(std::ostream& os, const T (&a)[N])
{
    return os << std::basic_string<T>(a, a+N) << std::endl;
}

// ....

wchar_t[] whello = L"Hello world";
dump(std::wcerr, whello) << std::endl;

unsigned char[] hello = "Hello world";
dump(std::cout, hello) << std::endl;

char buf[2048];
std::ofstream ofs("out.bin", std::ios::binary);
dump(ofs, buf);
```

Comment: You could write `operator <<` instead of `dump`. That way, you would be able to write `std::cout << whello << ", "  << hello << ", " << buf`.

Comment: @Nawaz, well I don't really recommend my approach (ostream::write is better). But if you _did_ overload `operator<<` you would no longer be able to write `std::cout << "oops"` (the compiler will say: ambiguous overload: could be `const char*` or `const (char&)[5]`). Not a GoodThing(TM)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `copy` algorithm from the Standard Library.  If you want to output to the standard output, you send the contents to an `ostream_iterator` on `cout`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char my_chars[] = {'a','b','c'};

    copy( &my_chars[0], &my_chars[sizeof(my_chars)], ostream_iterator<char>(cout, "\t"));
}
```

You can also send the output to another stream, and then when that is done, dump the whole thing to `cout` in one shot:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char my_chars[] = {'a','b','c'};

    stringstream ss;
    copy( &my_chars[0], &my_chars[sizeof(my_chars)], ostream_iterator<char>(ss, "\t"));

    cout << ss.str() << endl;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that creating an intermediate copy is not the OP's intent (due to performance requirements). Also, this implementation has the 'trailing `\t`' problem.

Comment: This is just intended to demonstrate how the syntax works.  I obviously have no idea if OP wants the values to be tab-, comma-, space-seperated, or what have you.

Answer (score 0):

To decrease execution time, if the characters have to be formatted, I would buffer the output to a `std::ostringstream` and then copy the resulting string to the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy from the container to standard output.

For instance

```
using std::ostream_iterator;
using std::cout;
using std::begin;
using std::end;
using std::copy;


copy(arr.begin(), arr.end(), ostream_iterator<Type>(cout,”\n”)) ;
```

`std::ostream_iterator` constructs output iterator tied to given ostream.